# Run tests in multiple browsers with ruby + watir-webdriver + cucumber and parallel_tests gem

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Currently I use the parallel profile in cucumber.yml to load an environment specific file and hooks.rb to set the browser. I run my tests using 'parallel_cucumber features'. There is not much in my hooks.rb file:

```
Before do
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
end

After do 
  @browser.close
end
```

The profile looks like this:

```
parallel: FIG_NEWTON_FILE=local.yml --no-source --color --format pretty
```

Is there a way to change my hooks.rb file so that all features run against a set of browsers (firefox, chrome, safari)? Is possible to pass the file name or environment through the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely pass the environment name through the command line.  Check out my env.rb file:

```
case ENV['BROWSER']
  when 'ff', 'Firefox'
    browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    browser_name = 'Firefox'
  when 'chrome'
    browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
    browser_name = 'Chrome'
  when 'debug'
    debug_profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
    debug_profile.add_extension "firebug-1.9.1-fx.xpi"
    browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => debug_profile
    browser_name = 'Firefox (Firebug)'
  when 'mobile'
    mobile_profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
    mobile_profile['general.useragent.override'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en)
      AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0
      Mobile/1A535b Safari/419.3"
    browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => mobile_profile
    browser_name = 'Mobile'
  when 'headless'
    headless_profile = Headless.new
    headless_profile.start
    browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    browser_name = 'Firefox'
  else
   browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
   browser_name = 'Firefox'
end

if URLS[ENV['URL']].nil?
  environment = 'dev'
  url = 'http://' + URLS['dev']
  domain = URLS['dev']
else
  environment = ENV['URL'].upcase
  url = 'http://' + URLS[ENV['URL']]
  domain = URLS[ENV['URL']]
end

if ENV['CLIENT'].nil?
  client = 'user/password'
else
  client = ENV['CLIENT']
end

puts "Browser      " + browser_name
puts "URL          " + url
puts "Environment: " + environment
puts "Client:      " + client
puts "Domain:      " + domain

test_env = {   :browser => browser,
               :browser_name => browser_name,
               :url => url,
               :env => environment,
               :client => client,
               :login => nil,
               :domain => domain }
```

Now when I run cucumber, I call the environment by doing:

> Cucumber BROWSER=ff

Comment: Thanks Whitney! I will give that a try for browsers.